Seconds on the login screen and lock screen in sddm. KDE plasma 6.1.5. CachyOS Linux
I'm using CachyOS, which is a Linux-based system, specifically from the Arch Linux family. I have KDE Plasma 6.1.5 and SDDM version 0.21.0 (Wayland) and I would like to add seconds to the login screen and lock screen, but I don't know how to do it and I couldn't find a working solution online. Does anyone know how to do it?
